# Firebase when query is empty

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I perform a query using firebase to check if there are any objects that have a child with a certain value. The problem is if there are no such objects the code doesn't run. So in the code below if there are no objects that have a child with `facebookID` that is `17` the rest of the code will never run. Is there a way to determine when a query finds `0` results?

```
func previousUser(completion:(result:Bool)->Void){

    var queryFound = false
    print("check if user is previous")
    print(UserData.globalfacebookID)
    let ref = Firebase(url:"https://amber-torch-556.firebaseio.com/Users")
    ref.queryOrderedByChild("facebookID").queryEqualToValue(17).observeSingleEventOfType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in

    print(snapshot.childrenCount)
    print("query has ran")
    UserData.globalparseID = snapshot.key

    queryFound = true
    completion(result:queryFound)

})
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your ref to make sure it's valid.

and try this

```
        ref.queryOrderedByChild("facebookID").queryEqualToValue(17)
           .observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

              if snapshot.value is NSNull {
                 print("dude, snapshot was null")
              } else {
                 print(snapshot.key)
              }

        })
```

Change .ChildAdded to .Value and then check for NSNull

Answer (score 0):

To check whether a query returns 0 results, you can check the snapshot as following:

```
if snapshot.exists() {
   // write relevant logic here
}
else {
   // handle the case when a query finds 0 results 
}
```

In your case,

```
func previousUser(completion:(result:Bool)->Void){
var queryFound = false
print("check if user is previous")
print(UserData.globalfacebookID)
let ref = Firebase(url:"https://amber-torch-556.firebaseio.com/Users")
ref.queryOrderedByChild("facebookID").queryEqualToValue(17).observeSingleEventOfType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
    if snapshot.exists() {
        print(snapshot.childrenCount)
        print("query has ran")
        UserData.globalparseID = snapshot.key
        queryFound = true
        completion(result:queryFound)
    }
    else {

         // handle the case where query finds zero(0) results 
    }
})
```

Hope this helps !