# How Do I Stop The Network Indicator to Stop Spinning when there is nothing from firebase to grab

Tags: ios, swift, function, firebase

I have a function which is called when the view is loaded and when the user pulls down the table view to refresh the view. This function takes a snapshot and then puts the info on the tableView. I have a network activity indicator that is used. It works correctly when there is information to grab and He indicator stops spinning once the data has been fetched, but if there is no data to grab then it just keeps spinning. I want to make it stop spinning if there is no data to grab.

```
 ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in



        let userId = snapshot.key
        print(snapshot.childrenCount)

        //print("This is interesting...", snapshot.value)

        print(userId)

        if userId == uid {



        let bookRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("user-books").child(userId)



        bookRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            let bookID = snapshot.key

            print("This is new",snapshot.children)


            print(bookID,"sigh..")

            self.bookKey = snapshot.key



            let booksIDref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("books").child(bookID)



            booksIDref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in


                if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{


                    let book = Book()

                    book.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)


                    self.books.append(book)

                    print(book.Author)

                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    })




                }


                UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false

                }, withCancel: nil)


            }, withCancel: nil) }

       UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
        }, withCancel: nil)







}
```

Comment: You will need to listen for the `.value` event too if you want to detect the absence of any children. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35111574/firebase-when-query-is-empty

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you, I will try this soon and get back to you. Thanks again for Firebase's great customer service.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen it worked thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the correct way to do it with FrankvanPuffelen's help. I used `snapshot.exists ()`  I put it in the second snapshot since that is the one that would be empty if there where no items stored there. I used an if statement as a check and now it works excellently.

```
 ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        let userId = snapshot.key
        print(snapshot.childrenCount)
        print(userId)

        if userId == uid {
            let bookRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("user-books").child(userId)
            bookRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            let bookID = snapshot.key
            print("This is new",snapshot.children)
            self.bookKey = snapshot.key

            let booksIDref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("books").child(bookID)
            booksIDref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
                    let book = Book()
                    book.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
                    self.books.append(book)

                    print(book.Author)

                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    })
                }
                UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false                 
            }, withCancel: nil)

            if snapshot.exists(){
                UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
            }
        }, withCancel: nil) }
    }, withCancel: nil)
```